# Ideal way to use Pandas Apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

here is the use case I am trying to solve for:

I have a DataFrame which has following columns:

- Name
- Date
- SubscriptionID
- Sku
- Type(sale or refund)

What I am trying to do is to loop through the entire dataset sorted by Date ascending.

Once done the first instance of (subscriptionid and sku) should get a new value, say interval_value, of 1. While looping if the record comes again increment it if it is sale or do -1 if there is a refund.

essentially I am trying to figure out how many times has each subscription purchased.
A subcan have potentially 2 sku,s hence I would like to do this using the subId and Sku.

In theory I can loop through the whole data frame and process line by line.
HOwever I am looking for how would this be accomplished using Pandas, either using the Apply method or some other fashion that is more efficient.

EDITED:

[image]

This is the logic I would like to implement. (**how to calculate the Interval Column**).

Looking for your response.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @MichaelGardner I have updated the original ticket with the snippet of what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Any thoughts or comments from anyone !!